# Unlock a feature when the user shares the app via Facebook/Tweeter in iOS, Swift?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

Is there such feature that can be un-locked when the user shares my app via Facebook or Tweeter?

Like this:

1) The user clicks on "Share" button within my app

2) My app is then posted(shared or advertised) on the wall of the user's facebook

3) Some feature gets unlocked within my app

Comment: Please be aware that you are __not allowed__ to reward users for sharing in any way. What you are trying to achieve here, is against [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) – you should read that before proceeding.

Comment: Which category is that at?

Comment: 4.5: _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_ – click on the question mark behind that point, and it will bring up examples that explicitly show that what you want to do is not allowed.

Comment: If you do it your app will be pretty quickly be deactivated and not being able to be used any more

Comment: @WizKid what do you mean deactviated? who deactivates it?

Comment: Facebook will if you don't follow Facebook Platform Policies

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the Facebook sharing `delegate` method to know whether the user has successfully shared OR not.

Below is FB developer link  which show various sharing methods,according to your requirements.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Below are the methods in which you can know the sharing status

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results{

//UNLOCK THE APP FEATURE IN THIS METHOD

}
- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer{

}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"%@",error);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

See [iOS Facebook Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/facebook-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-post-to-a-user-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app) for an example of how its done on the facebook end.

On the app side you can setup a flag on NSUserDefaults or write to the app filesystem to check if the feature is unlocked.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done relatively painlessly using [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/) and its completion handler.

```
NSString *message = @"my app is awesome.";
NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"awesomeapp.com"];
UIActivityViewController *shareController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[message, link]
                                                                              applicationActivities:nil];
//add whatever you don't want
shareController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMessage]; 
shareController.completionWithItemsHandler = 
^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
    //Share wasn't completed, don't unlock
    if (!completed || activityError) {
        return;
    }
    //Facebook or Twitter
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] ||
        [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) {
        //Unlock item logic
    }
};
[self presentViewController:shareController animated:YES completion:^{
    //Whatever
}];
```